# Seeking commandline tool for intersecting Shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, intersection, software-recommendations

in QGIS vectorlayers can be intersected. That is apparently done by ftools and seems to be integrated into the QGIS-program itself.

That is different from many other functions that call GDAL-tools.

I would like to intersect esri-shapefiles in a script and without having to load anything into QGIS.

Is there a GDAL-tool or some other commandline-suite that will do this?

It would be nice to have a tool that handles the shapefile natively (GDAL-tools do that) without having to import it or convert it to some internal format.

An alternate solution would be a commandline-interface to ftools.

Answer (score 4):

[[gdal-dev] Intersect of two shapefiles](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2009-January/019539.html) on the gdal-dev mailing list by Warmerdam himself says it's not possible with gdal tools directly, but it can be programmed using one of the available language wrappers (i.e. Python):

> The key method is OGRGeometry::Intersection() which when invoked
> on one geometry with another geometry will return a new geometry which is
> their intersection.

> Note that this method depends on GDAL/OGR having been built against the GEOS
> geometry library which really does the work.